# What's wrong with the for loop in VB?

Tags: vb.net

I totally don't get it , why i got a `Additional information: Bad file name or number` when Button1 was clicked in VS2008SP1 ?

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Do
        i += 1
        Print(i)

        If i >= 10 Then
            Print "I is above 10"
        ElseIf i >= 20 Then
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop While (i <= 30)
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't really know VB, but I expect the problem might be with the `Print` statements - where would you expect that output to go? Do you have to open an output file first? Does the problem happen if you remove the `Print` statements? Does the problem happen if you remove everything *except* a `Print` statement?

Comment: This appears to be the least ideal loop construct you could have chosen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use Print(). `Print()` function is used to write data into a file. To print number in debug window use `Debug.Print()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You're misusing the print function - 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9cksc646(v=vs.90).aspx

Are you trying to output to the console or the debug window perhaps?